# Navigation (pagination) inside articles like Google Current (Android)

Tags: android, navigation, pagination

I would like some help about an Android Application. I used the new Google Currents application and saw how the user can navigate inside an article. This is like the iOS' dots but with a bar instead of the dots.

Can you give me some clue about how google did it ? I'm not asking the code but the way to do it because I can't figure out how to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a ViewPager with a ViewPagerIndicator like the one in Google Currents

More on

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

[ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/):

You are referring to the 'circles' ViewPagerIndicator like so:

[image]

For more information, try downloading the [sample ViewPagerIndicator app from the play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample)